# 404 page not working when mistaken in methods

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I put the line

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';
```

in the routes.php file, and I made a controller with a name `my404`:

```
<?php

include 'page.php';

class My404 extends Page {
    private $page;
    public function __construct() {
        $page = new stdClass();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        // $this->page->page_title = "Page not found!";
        $this->page_view($this->load->view('my404', $this->page, true));
    }
}
?>
```

and I made a View with a name of `my404`
It is working **fine** when I make a syntax error in the controller name, but it won't work if I write a wrong method and a `Server error` will occur instead of the customized 404 page, have I missed something in the `routes.php` file ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Codeigniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html):

> This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the **requested controller** is not found.

Apparently that rout will only work when controller isn't found.

you can instead override the default error_404 page at 'application/errors/error_404.php'.